# term wise product of power series converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Suppose we have non-negative valued sequences $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$, $(b_n)_{n=1}^\infty$.
We know that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_n =\infty$ diverges, but $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{n}b_{n}=L$ converges to some real number $L$.

In this case, what can we say about the sequence $b_n$?

What if we add in extra condition that $a_n\to 0$ monotonically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can say nothing about a convergence of $b_n$.

Obviously, $b_n$ may be convergent, because the case $b_n = 0 $ is possible.

Fix $a_n$. Let us construct  divergent $b_n \in \{ 0, 1 \}$ such that $\sum_n a_n b_n$ converges.

As $a_n \to 0$ and $a_n \ge 0$, we may take subsequence $n_k$ such that $a_{n_k} < \frac{1}{k^2}$ and $n_{k+1} > n_{k} + 2$.  Put $b_m = 1$ if $m = n_k$ for some $k$ and $b_m = 0$ otherwise. Hence $\liminf_n b_n = 0$, $\limsup_n b_n =1$ and $b_n$ is divergent. Moreover, we have $\sum_{n} a_n b_n = \sum_{k} a_{n_k} \cdot 1 \le \sum_{k} \frac{1}{2^k} < \infty$. Thus $\sum_{n} a_n b_n $ converges, q.e.d.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So we can't say anything about the convergence of $b_n$, but can we say anything weaker? For example, with regard to $\lim\sup b_n$ or $\lim\inf b_n$?

Comment: We may, but just a little. Notice that $limsup_n b_n$ may be finite, as it was already proved. Also  $limsup_n b_n$ may be equal to $+\infty$ - it's sufficient to put $b_m = \sqrt{k}$ instead of $b_m = 1$ in my example. We can say only that $liminf_n b_n = 0$: otherwise $b_n > c > 0$ for $n > n_0$, and it follows from divergence of $\sum_n a_n$ that $\sum_n a_n b_n$ diverges - a contradiction. The answer is: we may say that $liminf_n b_n = 0$. Is that what you needed?

Comment: Yes, that clears things up, thanks.